# Quadratic Variation of a Semimartingale and jumps

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Consider the process $X(t) = A(t) + M(t)$, where $\{A\}$ is a finite variation predictable process and $\{M\}$ is a local martingale.

Suppose that $\{A\}$ does not have any jump, hence it is a continuous finite variation process. The quadratic variation of such process is $0$.

Is it right to conclude that $[X,X]_t$ = $[M,M]_t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Cauchy-Schwarz applies to the quadratic variation (you can see this from the definition of the QV), so

$$[A,M]_t^2 \le [A,A]_t[M,M]_t = 0,$$
and

$$[X,X]_t = [A,A]_t + 2[A,M]_t + [M,M]_t = [M,M]_t.$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why do we need to exploit Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? Is it to  explicitly show that $[A,M]^2_t = 0$ which in turn implies $[A,M]_t = 0$?

Comment: @ResidualClaimant Yes, exactly. It's intuitive that $[A, M]_t = 0$, but Cauchy-Schwarz is how you prove it.